# Python load HTML code from PostgreSQL Database

Tags: python, html, postgresql

I have a database table for my blog entries where I save certain content as html code. Then I load this content and expect it to excute the html code, but it does not do it. All the html code symbols seem broken.

My DB column:

[image]

Loading column content in template (red square shows where I want to load the column content:

[image]

HTML code after the column content has been loaded:

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to load this properly so the html will be executed, because in the DB it looks ok.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML content is being *escaped* by Django as a default behavior. To mark this content as safe for rendering, you can use the [`safe` template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe):

> Marks a string as not requiring further HTML escaping prior to output. When autoescaping is off, this filter has no effect.

In your example, this should work:

```
{{ blog.bloginhalt|safe }}
```

Alternatively, if you have many tags that will need to be marked as `safe`, you can set [`autoescape`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape) to `on` for a whole block:

```
{% autoescape off %}
    {{ tag1 }}
    {{ tag2 }}
    {{ tag3 }} <!-- all these tags are not escaped -->
{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked, will accept in 10 min.